# Google map overflow like in foursquare app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, gradient

I am trying to integrate map in my android app similar like in foursquare. I need to make part of the map transparent and then covered with text. Does anyone know how to do that?

Here is an example:

[image: Example is presented here.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using a `RelativeLayout` and setting a gradient background:

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Your layout here"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**gradient.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:startColor="#ffffff"
        android:endColor="#00ffffff" />

</shape>
```

**MapsActivity.java** (trivial, but completes the example)

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(40, -4)));
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]